# How to create GIF file from layout(view)?

Tags: android, gif

I want to save GIF from view or layout in android. please help.

Right now in my app, i am save image from view by following code

```
public Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap; 
}
```

so can i save gif image from layout or any other way to save my view as GIF?

Comment: Android itself has very little GIF support. Most likely you will need a third-party library, and many of those will be focused on displaying GIFs, not creating them. [This library](https://github.com/waynejo/android-ndk-gif) offers options for creating GIFs, though it seems optimized for animated GIFs.

Comment: Basically my app is image editor or creates an image with a sticker like Instagram. 
and add gif image on same background image.

Comment: @B001ᛦyes, i am loading gif file on some background imageView and i want to save background with that loaded gif